# How to use Tibco Certified Messaging Mode

Tags: java, tibco

How do I use Tibco Certified Messaging mode?  Does WebsphereMQ provide the same functionality?  Does the JMS specification define this functionality?

Comment: Which MQ are you talking about? If you mean Websphere MQ, why don't you ask them as its a commercial product? (If they don't know, no body does) If you mean ActiveMQ, or HornetQ, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are looking for a message transport that offers guaranteed delivery. E.g. if the recipient of the message is not available, the message will be delivered when the recipient comes back online again?

TIBCO Rendezvous has a mode called Rendezvous Certified Messaging (RVCM) that stores messages on disk until all recipients has acknowledged it. Both TIBCO EMS and Websphere MQ allows configuring persistent destinations with similar functionality. For details on how to configure and use these please refer to the documentation provided by either vendor for your particular language.

JMS, which is a specification and not an implementation as the above, states that when a message is marked as persistent, the JMS provider must "take extra care to insure the message is not lost in transit due to a JMS provider failure". Please note that both TIBCO EMS and Websphere MQ can be accessed using the JMS API.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of TIBCO RVCM in the JMS/EMS world is 'PERSISTENT' messaging to a durable subscription, more specifcially: use publish(..,DeliverMode.PERSISTENT,..) on the publisher and Session.createDurableSubscriber(..) on the consuming side.

That way you will ensure that every message published to this topic will end up at the subscriber, even if the subscriber is down for a while and that all messages are stored on disk before delivery, so it will survived tibemsd downtimes.

But be careful: unlike RVCM, where messages were stored on the publisher, with EMS messages are stored on the daemon (tibemsd), so one subscriber that is not picking up messages will let the memory and disk of the tibemsd grow and grow. Make sure you configure max_msg_memory and msg_swapping and TEST this !

with RVCM one rouge subscriber might influence only the publishers that are actually publishing to it, with EMS one rouge subscriber can influence memory and performance of the whole system.